# How to find out what specific actions are scheduled by MSI after reboot

Tags: reboot, windows-installer

When an MSI detects some process holding a resource that needs modifying, and user declines to close the process, MSI postpones the modification to the reboot time.

The question is: where to look for the list of such actions scheduled to run after reboot (after I installed the application, and was notified that the reboot is necessary, but didn't reboot yet)? I need to understand what exactly is that in an application's installer that requests closing seemingly unrelated process (on first install of the application in question), and finding the offending DLL/registry key/whatever could hopefully help identifying (and possibly ultimately fixing) the issue in the application's installer (namely, LibreOffice reportedly asking to close Firefox).

I believe that this question is properly asked here at SuperUser as opposed to StackOverflow, since, despite the ultimate goal is fixing an application, the immediate problem is detecting the postponed actions in user space.

Thanks!

Comment: :-) I'm a LibreOffice developer - so any LibreOffice (e.g., current master). I don't know the FF versions - the issue is reported by users who didn't tell the versions (yet); but the question does not depend on a specific version of any software - it asks for something MSI-specific, not LO- or FF-specific. If I get the info, I'd pass it to those users to gather the info and provide in a proper bug report, to handle it then.

Comment: Oh, I just got "Running Windows 10, Firefox 65.0.1 and LibreOffice 6.2.0.3" response from user (just in case :-)).

Comment: Possibly the answer is indicated in the [MoveFileEx documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) (under Remarks, discussing MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT and its registry keys).